# Multithreading : defining thread as a class

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have the following program that I wrote to implement thread as a class.

```
import threading
import datetime
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i=i

    def prints(self):
        while(self.i>0):
            print "i="+str(self.i)+" "+str(datetime.datetime.now().time())+"\n"
            self.i=self.i-1
            time.sleep(1)
        return

t1=MyThread(3)
t2=MyThread(5)
time.sleep(1)
t1.start()
t2.start()
#t1.join()
#t2.join()
```

Even though it executes without throwing any errors, I don't see the output I'm expecting i.e, prints of i=3 to 1 in one thread and prints of i=5 to 1 in another thread. In fact, there is no output at all. And the code looks fine to me. I even tried adding sleep statements, no avail. What could possibly have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never call `prints` function , you should call `prints` in `run` function that overrides from `Thread` class:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i=i
   def run(self):
        self.prints()
```

and also you should import `datetime` and this is output:

```
i=3 16:55:36.903809
i=5 16:55:36.904809


i=2 16:55:37.966870
i=4 16:55:37.967870


i=1 16:55:38.972927
i=3 16:55:38.973927


i=2 16:55:39.979985

i=1 16:55:40.984042
```

Comment: That was helpful. I missed the datetime import statement. Have edited the post to include it. Appreciate pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere do you *call* `prints()`; you merely define it.  If you call it `run` instead, the threading class will call it.  You could also keep the name but define a separate `run` method that calls it.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. So, run() is a function that's called implicitly by the threading class and any other function needs to be explicitly called?